# Could not cast value of type 'Swift._NativeDictionaryStorageOwner<Swift.String, Swift.AnyObject>' (0x40c2134) to 'NSArray' (0x383bb8d8)

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7.3

Upon revisiting some code that seemed to work with Xcode7.3, I noticed that I am getting a Could not cast value of type 'Swift._NativeDictionaryStorageOwner' (0x40c2134) to 'NSArray' (0x383bb8d8).

userdata.data = userOtherInfo[indexPath.row] as! NSArray

Here is the section of code that appears to be the problem:

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,        didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let userdata:SubContentsViewController! = SubContentsViewController()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SubContentsViewController", bundle: nil)
    let subContentsVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SubContentsViewController") as! SubContentsViewController
    userdata.data = userOtherInfo[indexPath.row] as! NSArray
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(subContentsVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: What is the content of  `userOtherInfo[indexPath.row]` ? Seems like you are trying to convert NSDictionary to NSArray

Comment: guard let value = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject],
                            rows = value["search_result"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]      else {
                                print("Malformed data received from fetchAlldatas service")
                                return
                        }   self.userOtherInfo = rows

Comment: As I suspected the userOtherInfo contains dictionaries. So you can't convert that to NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote in your comment

> `rows = value["search_result"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]`
>   `self.userOtherInfo = rows`

`rows / userOtherInfo` is an array of **dictionaries** (`[[String: AnyObject]]`) on success.
That's what the error message says :

> Cannot cast Dictionary to Array.

The solution is very very simple.

Since the compiler already knows that `userOtherInfo` contains an array of `[String: AnyObject]` you need no casting at all.

```
userdata.data = userOtherInfo[indexPath.row] // object is [String:AnyObject]
```

Make sure that `userdata.data` is declared as `[String:AnyObject]` or a more specific dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working fine for me.
let mutableDict = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: newDictionaryResult!)